# ArrayList just add the last element for all positions

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my whole code, it's quite complex but please help me. It's taken me for 2 days but I failed:

```
public static ArrayList<DocGia> XuatDocGia() throws IOException {
    ArrayList<DocGia> listDocGia = new ArrayList<>();
    File fileDocGia = new File("fileDocGia.txt");
    if(fileDocGia.exists() == false) {
        System.out.println("Chưa có đọc giả nào trong thư viện");
    } else {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileDocGia.txt"));     
        if (br.readLine() == null) {
            System.out.println("Chưa có đọc giả nào trong thư viện");
        } else {
            int soDong = DemSoDong("fileDocGia.txt");
            int dongHienTai = 0;
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(fileDocGia);
            for(int i = 0, z = 0;;i++, z++) {
                DocGia docGia = null;
                System.out.println("***Đọc giả thứ: " + (i+1));
                docGia.tendocgia = fileScanner.nextLine();
                if(i >= 1) {
                    docGia.tendocgia = fileScanner.nextLine();
                }
                docGia.maDocGia = fileScanner.nextLine();
                docGia.soSachmuon = fileScanner.nextInt();
                docGia.thoiGianMuonSach = fileScanner.nextInt();
                listDocGia.add(docGia);
                docGia.XuatDocGia();
                dongHienTai += 4;
                if(dongHienTai == soDong) {
                    fileScanner.close();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    for(DocGia docGia: listDocGia) {
        docGia.XuatDocGia();
    }
  }
  return listDocGia;
}
```

look at my code, when i run:

`docGia.XuatDocGia();`

-> the value of every single element is right at debug. it also means the value of the variable inside is right. but at the end of this function. i run

```
for(DocGia docGia: listDocGia) {
    docGia.XuatDocGia();
}
```

this is `XuatDocGia` funtion:

```
    public static void XuatDocGia(){
    System.out.println(tendocgia);
    System.out.println(maDocGia);
    System.out.println(soSachmuon);
    System.out.println(thoiGianMuonSach);
}
```

It just shows for me the last element in this ArrayList, repeat in 3 times( equal the number of elements).

I think a problem come from adding process of `listDocGia.add(docGia);`

You guys no need to bother everything else in my code, because i know it's really complex. I have tested carefully, just focus on my problem.

I'm so sorry because i'm Vietnamese and beginner at Java. The next time everything will be English. Thank you so much.

Comment: the code doesn't really seem complex, but we don't know what it is supposed to do, so, what are we looking at?

Comment: Is that the actual code? The `DocGia docGia = null;` means that you should be getting a NullPointerException.

Comment: to add to Eran's point: DemSoDong("fileDocGia.txt"); what does the DemSoDong method do? And what are the contents of that file?

Comment: I cant see how this works at all,  because `DocGia` object is never intialised.

Comment: @Stultuske it is supposed to take all data in fileDocGia.txt into ArrayList: listDocGia. but when i print it to console. it repeats 3 times by the value of last element.

Comment: @jr593 you are expecting NullPointer Exception but if the field is static it won't throw NullPointerException. Have a look Eran's answer ;)

Comment: @PhanThếKhương You should read about `static` and avoid using `static` everywhere

Comment: Oh my God, vietnam  variable names.. I checked it in Google Translate, because I was curious :)

Comment: @Eran. but it will be updated in for loop. @ this method count how many rows in file, it works really fine, i took it from our community. the contents of this file is: how can i highlighted it at here?
"
Phan Thế Khương
PTK
34
2
LÊ Can
LC
4
6
Đặng DUng
DD
3
4
"

Comment: If the file is read well, you just create a constructor in DocGia class and parameters all properties to constructor. Create local variables: `maDocGia`, `soSachMuon`, `thoiGianMuonSach`. Then create new object docGia by contrcutor: `DocGia docGia = new DocGia(maDocGia, soSachMuon, thoiGianMuonSach);`, add it to `ArrayList`.

Comment: @jr593 how can i do to solve it?

Comment: @PhanThếKhương you are assigning your data to static variables, so in each iteration of the loop you overwrite the previously assigned values.

Comment: @YusufK. i understand. but i'm still beginner, i'm reading a good book about java. haha

Comment: @PhanThếKhương: University of Science, my school. If you're studying Java, maybe your teacher is Mr. Thảo

Comment: @ĐăngKhoaHuỳnh it's not work by this way. i have tried it before. i'm learning Java by myself right now.

Comment: Show me all your code, and I will tell you how to fix. I think it is not complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the actual code, you are adding null references to your List, but since you are using a static method to print the values, you don't get a `NullPointerException`. Assuming your code passes compilation, this means all the members of the `DocGia` class are static, which explains why you get the same values in each iteration of your loop.

You should change

```
DocGia docGia = null;
```

to

```
DocGia docGia = new DocGia ();
```

and change all the members of `DocGia` (including the `XuatDocGia` method that prints them) to be non static.

Comment: but when i change all the members to be non static. getter and setter of them requires me they have to be static?

Comment: @PhanThếKhương Why do you think they have to be static? They shouldn't be static, since each object should have different values.

Comment: but you right. when i check it out. everything is null.